Every midnight laravel.log ownership is changing
At midnight laravel<date>.log file owner is changed to ubuntu so to overcome this issue I run a cron job to change the owner to www-data.
rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu       4154 Aug 14 11:41 laravel-2024-08-14.log

Why are the changes happening at midnight? How can I resolve this?

Do you have the project run as someone else (ie: root)? Depending on how you have laravel logging setup, it may be rotating to daily logs, meaning you get a fresh log every day, which is what a lot of the viewing packages require. That's likely why it's changing out every day at midnight Ideally, you want laravel in a dedicated user environment (ie: /home/user) with the logs and everything run, and owned by that user. It's not that hard to go there and do that.
